# How to disable pocket mode in android by java code

Tags: android

I want to disable pocket mode for my application, maybe by intent, maybe by adding permission or something like this. How can I do this kind of work?

Comment: Please explain **in detail** what "pocket mode" is.

Comment: Pocket Dial Prevention Mode. When the top of the screen is closed, write do not close the top of the screen. How do I disable this feature for my application?

Comment: Ask your device manufacturer. Android itself does not have a "pocket dial prevention mode" -- this is something that your device manufacturer has added to its device and its build of Android.

Answer (score 0):

Try Wakelock

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock( PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "FullWakeLock" );
```